# Blogger - iframe Code doesn't work, after the recommended corrections it doesn't appear on my blog

Tags: html, iframe, embed, blogger

I know there are many questions about the iframe codes. But I still can't get any help from the other questions. I want to insert some counters from the `World Counts`. But the code they provide seems to have a fault or maybe Blogger doesn't accept how it's written.

> The main problems are
>
> 1. The reference to entity "color" must end with the ';' delimiter
> 2. The entity "color" was referenced, but not declared.

It is also the same for the `font_family, font_size and token`.

I added the ';' where was needed and declared the entities color=white& to color=white& amp;

```
<iframe height='100' src='http://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/ocean_ecosystem_facts/coral_reef_destruction_facts/embed?background_color=white&color=black&font_family=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Arial%2C+sans-serif&font_size=14&token=ccfd8c44a4686cada3a2e343f1d56a9b98ac49d4' style='border: none' width='300'></iframe>
```

Even though after the correction Blogger accepts the code, but the counter doesn't appear at all at the site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the `&` symbol present in the iframe tag's `src` link. You will need to escape it by replacing it with `&amp;` to make the iframe tag get accepted by Blogger's XML parser. Also switching to HTTPS protocol will make sure that `mixed content` error doesn't occur

```html
<iframe height='100' src='https://www.theworldcounts.com/counters/ocean_ecosystem_facts/coral_reef_destruction_facts/embed?background_color=white&amp;color=black&amp;font_family=%22Helvetica+Neue%22%2C+Arial%2C+sans-serif&amp;font_size=14&amp;token=ccfd8c44a4686cada3a2e343f1d56a9b98ac49d4' style='border: none' width='300'></iframe>
```